# How to manage memory consumption of Celery/RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, multiprocessing, celery

I use celery/rabbitmq to visit pages on the Internet. As some pages are heavy, I have spikes in memory usage, so after a while the average load of celery and the system raise too much.

```
top - load average: 74.91, 128.04, 173.44
Tasks: 3449 total,  88 running, 3353 sleeping,   0 stopped,   8 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.9 us, 94.8 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.1 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8175376 total,  8071820 used,   103556 free,     2256 buffers
KiB Swap:  8386556 total,  8386556 used,        0 free.    65620 cached Mem
```

It hits the swap and most of the tasks get timeout. So I want to decrease the number of processes or workers to keep the memory usage under 80%. The only way I found that can grows and shrinks processes dynamically is the '--autoscale' option, but it works in the opposite way,

> autoscaler adds more pool processes when there is work to do,
>   and starts removing processes when the workload is low.

So is there any other solutions I can use? Should I Monitor memory usage myself and then use [celery.app.control](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html) methods like :

```
Control.pool_shrink(n=1, destination=None, **kwargs)[source]
```

To shrink the size? Is there any easier solution for that?